# Good libraries for lattice-crypto

Tags: implementation, lattice-crypto

I'm searching good libraries to manipulate lattice tools to do cryptography.

I'm mainly interested by C/C++. But I'm also interested if it is in python.

Comment: "good" is opinion based and makes your question off topic on SE.